# Blender export to JSON for THREE.js missing Materials

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

Good day,

I am trying to export a model I've made in Blender to JSON format so that I can use it in my THREE.js web application. Everything works fine except for the fact that it doesn't seem to export the materials correctly. In Blender, my model is colored, but when viewed in the web browser with THREE.js, the model is grey.

Here is what both outputs look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zIMG.png

This is the code for loading the JSON file into the program:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("../tankSingleObject2.json", addModel );
function addModel(geometry, materials) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, materials);
    scene.add(mesh);
    mesh.position.z = -2;
}
```

And here is what the JSON file looks like:

```
{
"vertices":[0.202124,0.554841,0.275849,0.402124,0.554841,0.275849,0.202124,0.554841,0.0758486,0.402124,0.554841,0.0758486,-0.404745,0.554792,0.279759,-0.204745,0.554792,0.279759,-0.404745,0.554792,0.0797591,-0.204745,0.554792,0.0797591,-0.61,0.0287037,0.321036,-0.61,0.528704,0.321036,-0.61,0.0287037,0.0030361,-0.61,0.528704,0.00303607,0.61,0.0287037,0.321036,0.61,0.528704,0.321036,0.61,0.0287037,0.0030361,0.61,0.528704,0.00303607,-0.594359,0.529223,0.305839,-0.594359,0.529223,0.0182327,0.594359,0.529223,0.0182327,0.594359,0.529223,0.305839,-0.594359,0.0387877,0.30584,-0.594359,0.0387877,0.0182327,0.594359,0.0387877,0.0182327,0.594359,0.0387877,0.30584,0,0.118215,0.0370853,0,0.318215,0.137085,0.019509,0.118215,0.0390067,0.0382684,0.118215,0.0446973,0.055557,0.118215,0.0539383,0.0707107,0.118215,0.0663746,0.083147,0.118215,0.0815282,0.0923879,0.118215,0.0988169,0.0980785,0.118215,0.117576,0.1,0.118215,0.137085,0.0980785,0.118215,0.156594,0.092388,0.118215,0.175354,0.083147,0.118215,0.192642,0.0707107,0.118215,0.207796,0.055557,0.118215,0.220232,0.0382683,0.118215,0.229473,0.019509,0.118215,0.235164,-2.98023e-08,0.118215,0.237085,-0.0195091,0.118215,0.235164,-0.0382684,0.118215,0.229473,-0.0555571,0.118215,0.220232,-0.0707107,0.118215,0.207796,-0.083147,0.118215,0.192642,-0.092388,0.118215,0.175354,-0.0980785,0.118215,0.156594,-0.1,0.118215,0.137085,-0.0980785,0.118215,0.117576,-0.0923879,0.118215,0.0988168,-0.0831469,0.118215,0.0815281,-0.0707106,0.118215,0.0663745,-0.0555569,0.118215,0.0539382,-0.0382682,0.118215,0.0446972,-0.0195089,0.118215,0.0390067,0.612,0.5154,-8.9407e-08,-0.612,0.5154,2.98023e-08,0.612,0.5514,-8.9407e-08,-0.612,0.5514,2.98023e-08,0.612,0.515076,0.327056,-0.612,0.515076,0.327056,0.612,0.551076,0.327056,-0.612,0.551076,0.327056,0.612,0,-5.96046e-08,-0.612,0,5.96046e-08,0.612,0.036,-5.96046e-08,-0.612,0.036,5.96046e-08,0.612,-0.000323951,0.327056,-0.612,-0.000323951,0.327056,0.612,0.035676,0.327056,-0.612,0.035676,0.327056],
"faces":[3,0,1,3,2,0,3,4,5,7,6,0,3,8,9,11,10,1,3,10,11,15,14,1,3,14,15,13,12,1,3,12,13,9,8,1,3,10,14,12,8,1,3,13,15,18,19,1,3,19,18,22,23,1,3,11,9,16,17,1,3,9,13,19,16,1,3,15,11,17,18,1,3,22,21,20,23,1,3,17,16,20,21,1,3,16,19,23,20,1,3,18,17,21,22,1,2,24,25,26,2,2,26,25,27,2,2,27,25,28,2,2,28,25,29,2,2,29,25,30,2,2,30,25,31,2,2,31,25,32,2,2,32,25,33,2,2,33,25,34,2,2,34,25,35,2,2,35,25,36,2,2,36,25,37,2,2,37,25,38,2,2,38,25,39,2,2,39,25,40,2,2,40,25,41,2,2,41,25,42,2,2,42,25,43,2,2,43,25,44,2,2,44,25,45,2,2,45,25,46,2,2,46,25,47,2,2,47,25,48,2,2,48,25,49,2,2,49,25,50,2,2,50,25,51,2,2,51,25,52,2,2,52,25,53,2,2,53,25,54,2,2,54,25,55,2,2,55,25,56,2,2,56,25,24,2,2,56,24,26,2,2,26,27,28,2,2,28,29,30,2,2,30,31,32,2,2,32,33,34,2,2,34,35,36,2,2,36,37,38,2,2,38,39,40,2,2,40,41,42,2,2,42,43,44,2,2,44,45,46,2,2,46,47,48,2,2,48,49,50,2,2,50,51,52,2,2,52,53,54,2,2,54,55,56,2,2,56,26,28,2,2,28,30,32,2,2,32,34,36,2,2,36,38,40,2,2,40,42,44,2,2,44,46,48,2,2,48,50,52,2,2,52,54,56,2,2,56,28,32,2,2,32,36,40,2,2,40,44,48,2,2,48,52,56,2,2,56,32,40,2,2,40,48,56,2,3,57,58,60,59,3,3,61,62,64,63,3,3,57,59,63,61,3,3,60,58,62,64,3,3,65,66,68,67,3,3,69,70,72,71,3,3,65,67,71,69,3,3,68,66,70,72,3],
"metadata":{
    "generator":"io_three",
    "version":3,
    "type":"Geometry",
    "materials":4,
    "faces":86,
    "vertices":73
},
"materials":[{
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgIndex":0,
    "wireframe":false,
    "opacity":1,
    "blending":1,
    "shading":"phong",
    "doubleSided":false,
    "DbgName":"Material.007",
    "specularCoef":50,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "visible":true
},{
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgIndex":1,
    "wireframe":false,
    "opacity":1,
    "blending":1,
    "shading":"phong",
    "doubleSided":false,
    "DbgName":"Material.006",
    "specularCoef":50,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "DbgColor":15597568,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "visible":true
},{
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgIndex":2,
    "wireframe":false,
    "opacity":1,
    "blending":1,
    "shading":"phong",
    "doubleSided":false,
    "DbgName":"Material.005",
    "specularCoef":50,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "DbgColor":60928,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "visible":true
},{
    "depthTest":true,
    "DbgIndex":3,
    "wireframe":false,
    "opacity":1,
    "blending":1,
    "shading":"phong",
    "doubleSided":false,
    "DbgName":"Material",
    "specularCoef":50,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "DbgColor":238,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "visible":true
}]}
```

The Blender file can be viewed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9u7kr6rqqciknh/tankSingleObject1.blend?dl=0

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you post the `.blend` file somewhere?

Comment: From what I can see, StackOverflow doesn't allow me to embed the .blend file anywhere here.

Comment: Correct, it does not. But I don't think we can help much without that sorry. Google Drive, Dropbox, or similar services can be used.

Comment: I have updated the question to include a link to the Dropbox file.

Comment: Ok, I don't have a good answer but I suspect the three.js exporter is having trouble with the BSDF materials... may want to file a bug on the three.js GitHub repo. Also, are you using the [latest version of the three.js blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender)?

Answer (score 0):

Luckily after messing around, I was able to find a solution. For anyone else who is in the same boat, switch from Cycles to Blender Renderer.